# The most read book custom post (find the top post with the same title)

Tags: wordpress, count, title

As the title says, i have a custom post type named book.
Each user can create another custom post type named read_book only if the "book" post type with that name exist.
So now i'm trying to display the most read book by getting that post name which has the most occurrences with the same title.
Is that possible ?
Thank you!

PS: If i would have 3 read_books with the name A, 2 with the name B and one with the name C, i would like to display the book post with the name A.

Edit: This is how it should look

```
// initial query to get the title
$read_books = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'read_book',
    'posts_per_page' => 1, // only the title is needed, so one post is enough
    'meta_key' => 'title', // here should happen the magic
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'date_query' => array( // optional ( most read book from past 30 days )
      'after' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')), // don't query the whole database
    )
));

if ($read_books->have_posts()): 
    while ($read_books->have_posts()): $read_books->the_post();
    $book_title = get_the_title;
    endwhile;
endif;

// final query
$most_read_book = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'book',
    's' => $book_title; // it should be only one book with that title because users can't add custom titles
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
));

if ($most_read_book->have_posts()): 
    while ($most_read_book->have_posts()): $most_read_book->the_post();
    // book info displayed on frontend
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: Please share what you've done and after that, we can, and would love to help you.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. The meta_key and orderby is just an example. I know it won't work because it will look for a number. That's why i posted here my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, but i'm not sure if is the best one. Yet, it works just fine.
Maybe there's a faster one.

```
//get the title string
$booksQuery = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'read_book',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'no_found_rows' => true,
    'date_query' => array(
      'after' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-90 days')), 
    )
));
$allTitles = array();
if ($booksQuery->have_posts()): 
    while ($booksQuery->have_posts()): $booksQuery->the_post();
        $allTitles[] = get_the_title();
    endwhile;
endif;
$allTitles = array_count_values($allTitles); // group titles 
asort($allTitles); // sort titles by number of occurrences
$topTitle = key( array_slice( $allTitles, -1, 1, TRUE ) ); // get the needed title
$finalTitle = str_replace([' – ', ' — ', ' - '], ' ', $topTitle); // the title is stored with a different character in database, so just remove it from title

//final query
$mrQuery = new WP_Query(array(
    's' => $finalTitle,
    'post_type' => 'book',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'no_found_rows' => true,
));

// the frontend code here..
```